# How do I get style.visibility to work with an external stylesheet? (vanilla javascript only, no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a project that requires me to implement it with purely vanilla Javascript. I want to perform an action based on whether an element is visible or not, so instead of jQuery's "is:visible", I'm trying to use Javascript's "object.style.visibility". The problem is that I cannot get it to return anything when using an external stylesheet. It only works if I style the html directly.

Here's the Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (evt)=>{
    visibility();
});
function visibility(){
    alert(document.getElementById("vis").style.visibility);
}
```

When I do the html like this, an alert window pops up that says "visible":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="vistest.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="vis" style="visibility:visible;">am I visible?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to link my stylesheet and remove the styling from the "p" tag, it doesn't work. An alert window pops up, but doesn't say anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistest.css">
    <script src="vistest.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="vis">am I visible?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's what's in my style sheet:

```
#vis{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I haven't been able to find any helpful information about this that doesn't involve jQuery. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Window​.get​Computed​Style()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (evt)=>{
    visibility();
});
function visibility(){  
  alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("vis")).visibility)
}
```

```css
#vis{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p id="vis">am I visible?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not set by default - use `computedStyle`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (evt) => {
  visibility();
});

function visibility() {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("vis")).visibility);
}
```

```css
#vis {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p id="vis">am I visible?</p>
```